# Photoshop-like range selection bar in Cocoa/iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am wondering how to make the typical "range selection" bar, as seen in Photoshop and many other applications. Cocoa/Cocoa Touch only provide the very basic slide bar.

[alt text http://ivzhao.com/temp/rangeCocoa.jpg](http://ivzhao.com/temp/rangeCocoa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's just Cocoa, but might be a good starting point (if just for getting an idea on how to subclass Apple's slider as NSSlider and UISlider probably have quite a lot in common I assume):
http:// developer.snowmintcs.com/controls/smdoubleslider/

In case you were actually looking for an element for gradient editing, you might like this BSD licensed "gradient compositing" element with support for color stops:
http://apptree.net/gcgradient.htm

Both are not for Cocoa-Touch in particular, but porting them (or adopting them for their iPhone counterparts) shouldn't be that hard, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could go crazy and handle it all yourself.  You could create a `UIView`, draw on it yourself, and implement `touchesDidBegin` and `touchDidEnd`.